# Deriving the derivative of $\tan^{2}x$ by quotient rule using (sinx/cosx) identity I am getting a different value (2secx(tanx+tan^2(x))

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Deriving the derivative of $\tan^{2}x$ by quotient rule using $$\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$$ identity,
 i am getting a different value $2\sec x[\tan x+\tan^{2}x]$ 
than by directly getting **chain rule** is $2\sec^{2}x\tan x$

Whats wrong?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @RandomGuy374 They are equivalent results - you should be able to get from one to another using trig identities.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a correct derivation of the derivative of $\tan^2 x$ using the quotient rule:

$$\dfrac d {dx} \tan^2 x = \dfrac d {dx} \dfrac {\sin^2 x}{\cos^2x }=\dfrac{2\sin x \cos x \cos^2x + \sin^2 x 2 \cos x \sin x}{\cos^4x}$$

$$=2\dfrac{\sin x(\cos^2x+\sin^2x)}{\cos^3x}=2\dfrac{\sin x}{\cos^3 x}=2\tan x \sec^2x$$

Comment: This is equivalent to 2sec^2(x)tan(x) you get by chain rule? And how does 1 check?

Comment: Yes, the chain rule yields $2 \tan x \sec^2x$ too

Comment: I forget, how does 1 derive that particular identity?... (cos^2x+sin^2x=1)

Comment: $\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x = 1$ is the [Pythagorean identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_trigonometric_identity)